# what knowledge required before working on a live streaming application

Tags: php, video-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

I am working on an online video streaming application, and I've been asked to work on the video streaming module.  But I don't have any knowledge regarding streaming.  After doing some search, I got some knowledge about different type of streaming like 1.On demand 2.Live video streaming, and I got a website like http://www.wowza.com which provides solutions for that.  Please give your valuable suggestions and some basic knowledge required before working on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php, javascript, jquery technologies. First you need a server that support (RTSP) Real Time Streaming Protocol . Most servers may not have this installed . Check if yours is, if not you need secondary server hosting plan only for streaming. Its not more expensive than regular hosting. Then in the system u need a plugin for managing streaming content and storage. The best and most easy I have come across is http://www.videowhisper.com/ .they have a very good video streaming code to customize and add to your site. If you have your own server, do a little research on red5 a program that helps setup broadcasting. Good luck

Comment: Why should he use RTSP?

Comment: for handling livestream. Thats the solution I know of